# Git Push Error | Bitbucket Repository

Tags: git, push, bitbucket

We are trying to push our local contents to our repository in "Bitbucket" but we are getting the following error while trying to "git push" after committing our files.

Error Message

```
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Can you people help us in this regards?

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem, this may help you:

```
#initialize git in the folder   
git init
#add remote repository (this did not work for me)
git remote add origin https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepo.git
#...so i changed it later (after some git add and commit commands)
git remote set-url origin https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepo.git
#now it worked:
git push -u origin master
```

If you get the error message `remote origin already exists`, run this:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I would add that: if you get the error message> fatal: ´ remote origin already exists.´ run this ´git remote rm origin´

Comment: whoever downvoted this, may i ask why? is something not correct in my answer? please explain, so i can improve it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks very much like you have failed to run a `git remote add` command.

Usually this would look like

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[USERNAME]/[REPONAME].git
```

But you should be able to find the correct info for your repository if you follow the docs here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Importing+code+from+an+existing+project

Answer (score 0):

You may try `git push --mirror url-of-your-bitbucket-remote`

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly ran following with 'i' missing in origin.

```
git remote add orign url
```

Only find out when view it using below command

```
git remote -v
```

and remove it using

```
git remote remove orign
```

and created it again with correct spelling using

```
git remote add origin url
```