# Intellij - Git Push via UI fails when private key contains a passphrase

Tags: git, intellij-idea, push, passphrase

It seems that when I use an ssh key with a passphrase, I am unable to push changes to github via the IntelliJ UI. I get the following error:

```
"Push failed: Failed with error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository."
```

But when I push through the command line, it works because I get prompted to input the passphrase.

I have already tried setting the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to point to TortoiseGitPlink.exe (I'm using an ssh agent) but still I get the same error.

Is there any other way for making this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. ssh-agent and ssh-pageant work for commandline but not intellij.

The final solution for me is to `create another ssh key pairs without passphrase`  (just press "Enter" when you are prompted with the "entering your passphrase" window).

If security is one of your main concerns, you can use the commandline git plus ssh-agent.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the settings, search git->ssh executable then choose native

As seen here : [git with IntelliJ IDEA: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566999/git-with-intellij-idea-could-not-read-from-remote-repository)

Comment: tried this already and it still throws an error. I end up using a key without a passphrase.