# git with pycharm works only from command line

Tags: git, ssh, command-line, pycharm, bitbucket

I have a private repository on bitbucket, some python code, which I pulled with git from the command line.
I then imported the project to Pycharm 2016.3.
From the command line I can push and pull, but git in Pycharm doesn't seems to work. I get errors like:
 `Fetch failed: Could not read from remote repository.`
I am using a ssh authentication, and I have set my .ssh/config to resolve bitbucket.org with the right private key. I have also configured Pycharm to use the native ssh, and not the built-in one.
I am stuck, Please help.

Comment: Check if you've set correct version control path in `Settings` > `Version Control`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it seems it is set correctly. It points to my project folder.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/31238453/3866610 out

Comment: Yes it is like that already, I mention that in my question too. "I have also configured Pycharm to use the native ssh, and not the built-in one."

Comment: Try starting fresh with pycharm  and download your project from bitbucket directly using pycharm. Just enter your git URL and let pycharm to the rest.

Comment: I tried, but failed. It says: "Could not read from remote repository"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was with the ssh key. The key prompts to insert a passphrase to allow to be used. Apparently pycharm is not able to deal with this. I changed the key with one that do not ask for a passphrase and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in PyCharm. The direct cause was that github "permanently removed support for the following weak cryptographic standards". See https://blog.github.com/2018-02-23-weak-cryptographic-standards-removed/

PyCharm has released new patches for this change. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/03/pycharm-2016-3-and-later-updated-for-github-compatibility/?fromIDE=